# Finding various measurements of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Trapezoid $ABCD$ satisfies $AB=5$, $BC=6$, $CD=3$, $AC=4$ and $AB||CD$. Let $O$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$.

[image]

Questions I'm trying to answer:

$1.)$ $\cos(\angle ABC)=?$

$2.)$ $BD= ?$

$3.)$ The area of $\Delta ABC=?$

$4.)$ $\sin(\angle ACD)=?$

$5.)$ The relationship between the areas of triangles $ABO$, $BCO$, $CDO$ and $DAO$ is $x:15:y:z$

---

So, I'm really bad at geometry, so please be patient with me.

Using the law of cosines I was able to find that $\cos(<ABC)=\frac{3}{4}$.

So, I'm trying to find $BD$ and I'm a bit stuck. I haven't used the fact that $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel, and I also suspect that there is some theorems about diagonals of a quadrilateral wilth a pair of parallel sides that will be useful.

I think I can find $(3)$ since I know $\cos(\angle ABC)=\frac{3}{4}$ and all the sides of $\Delta ABC$ (I can introduced a coordinate system and calculate a cross product).

I also am a bit stuck on $(4)$ and $(5)$ but I bet if I could figure out $(2)$ I could figure them out.

Anyway, I'm sure there are multiple ways to solve this problem. If you awesome saintly genius's that linger here could show me some methods I would be very grateful. Thanks I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1.) $\cos\angle ABC=\frac{3}{4}$.

2.) Since $AB\parallel CD$$,\;\angle BCD=180^{\circ}-\angle ABC\implies \cos(\angle BCD)=-\cos(\angle ABC)=-\frac{3}{4}$. You can apply Law of Cosines in $\triangle BCD$ and find $BD$.

3.) $[ABC]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot \sin(\angle ABC)$ and $\sin (\angle ABC)=\frac{1}{2}.$

4.) Apply Law of Sines in $\triangle ABC$, observe $\sin (\angle BAC)=\sin(\angle ACD)$ since $AB\parallel CD$.

5.) Let $[BCO]=15k$ and $[ABO]=25s$ some constants $k,s.$ Use the following results:

- $[ADC]=[BCD]\implies [DAO]=[BCO]=15k$
- $\frac{[CDO]}{[ABO]}=\frac{CD^2}{AB^2}=\frac{9}{25}$
- $\frac{OD}{OB}=\frac{[CDO]}{[BCO]}=\frac{[DAO]}{[ABO]}$

Comment: Can you explain to me $AB\parallel CD \rightarrow$$\;\angle BCD=180^{\circ}-\angle ABC$ from $2.)$?

Comment: If you extend ray $BC$ to some point $E$, $\angle ABC=\angle DCE$ (corresponding angles) and $\angle BCD=180^{\circ}-\angle DCE$ (linear pair). Corresponding angles are a property of parallel lines.

Comment: Can you please explain the first 2 bullet points of (5)? Also, how come you set [ABO]=25s? Where did the 25 come from?

Comment: The result follows from the observation $\triangle CDO \sim \triangle ABO$. [This](https://brilliant.org/wiki/congruent-and-similar-triangles/#area-and-perimeter-relations) might be helpful. $25s$ was my choice because I wanted a neat expression for $[CDO]$ which turns out to be $9s$. Note, $k$ and $s$ can be chosen depending upon the areas of $\triangle BCO$ and $\triangle ABO$, respectively.

Comment: $[ADC]=[BCD]$ since they have common side $BC$ and equal heights since $AB\parallel CD$.